# Error: Invalid configuration of route ''. One of the following must be provided: component, redirectTo, children or loadChildren

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router

I'm setting up ' ' path based on a condition which is working fine and setting up the route to ' ' path. I works fine on my development server. But when i build the project and run it on production server it gives me this error.

Uncaught Error: Invalid configuration of route ' '. One of the following must be provided: component, redirectTo, children or loadChildren

This is my app-routing.module.ts

```
const fallback: Route = {
  path: '**',
  component: NotFoundComponent
}

var   home: Route = {};

const hostName = window.location.host;
console.log('hostName: ', hostName);
var workspaceName = hostName.split('.')[0];
console.log('workspaceName: ', workspaceName);

if (workspaceName === 'peprix' || workspaceName === 'www') {
  console.log("if");
  let homeRoute: Route = {
    path: '', component: MainComponent
  }
  home = homeRoute;
} else {
  console.log("else");
  let homeRoute: Route = {
    path: '', canActivate: [SessionGuard], data: { workspaceName: workspaceName }, resolve: { workspaceId: SigninService }, component: SigninNextComponent
  }
  home = homeRoute;
}

const routes: Routes = [
  home,
  { path: 'signin', canActivate: [SessionGuard], component: SigninComponent, data: { workspaceName: workspaceName } },
  { path: 'create-workspace', canActivate: [SessionGuard], component: CreateWorkspaceComponent },
  { path: 'projects', canActivate: [ProjectGuard], component: ProjectComponent },
  { path: 'password-reset', component: PasswordResetComponent },
  { path: 'new-password', component: NewPasswordComponent },
  fallback
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  providers: [
    ProjectDetailsService,
    SigninService
  ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

P.S: I've imported all the components and dependencies so it ain't a problem here.

Comment: `var   home: Route = {};` home must not be empty [this comment might help someone in future]

Answer (score 2):

**I think this is the result of packaging optimization under the production mode of `Angular`.**

**Please take a look at this test first.**

When I try the following code, the result is the same:

- **error**: `Uncaught Error: Invalid configuration of route ''. One of the following must be provided: component, redirectTo, children or loadChildren`

```
var home: Route = {};

// No matter what you do later, it is invalid.
// The variable home assigned to routes is unchanged.
Home.path = '';
Home.component = HomeComponent;

// result: home = {}
// so error
const routes: Routes = [home];
```

- **right**

```
const home: Route = {
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent
}
```

Finally, for your problem solution, you can do something like this:

```
// Define them first
// MainComponent
const home: Route = {
    path: '',
    component: MainComponent
};

// SigninNextComponent
const home2: Route = {
    path: '',
    component: SigninNextComponent
}

// Your judgment parameters
const hostName = window.location.host;
var workspaceName = hostName.split('.')[0];

// Judge written here
const routes: Routes = [
    workspaceName === 'peprix' || workspaceName === 'www' ? home : home2,
    Fallback
];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you pass the empty object `{}` as part of the routes then this will also cause the above error.

So if for whatever reason you need to keep empty routes in your project as a placeholder, you can filter them out like this:

```
// foo-routing.module.ts
//
// import your routes here

const allRoutes: Routes[] = [
  // your routes
];

const filteredRoutes: Routes = allRoutes.reduce((accumulator, routeArray) => {
  const allObjectsConform = routeArray.every(route => Object.keys(route).length > 0);
  if (allObjectsConform) {
    return [...accumulator, ...routeArray];
  }
  return accumulator;
}, [] as Routes);


const routes: Routes = [
  ...filteredRoutes,
  
  // routes you want to define at the top level
  // ...
];
```

Since each route is an array of objects, you gotta test each object inside the array to check if it has no keys (in other words, if it's empty.)

This code will not filter out invalid route objects though, the ones that have wrong keys and values.