# Angular router error - Uncaught Error: Invalid configuration of route 'momentum'

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I'am trying to setup routes in Angular's app.

app-routing.module.ts

```
import {PreloadAllModules, RouterModule, Routes} from "@angular/router";

export const APP_ROUTES: Routes = [
  {
    path: "",
    redirectTo: "momentum",
    pathMatch: "full"
  },
  {
    path: "momentum",
    loadChildren(): any {
      return import('./pages/momentum/momentum.module').then(m => m.MomentumModule);
    }
  }
];

export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(APP_ROUTES, {
  preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules
});
```

momentum-routing.module.ts

```
import {RouterModule, Routes} from "@angular/router";
import {MomentumComponent} from "./momentum.component";

const ROUTES: Routes = [
  {
    path: "",
    component: MomentumComponent
  }
];

export const taskRouting = RouterModule.forChild(ROUTES);
```

I was thinking it is easy to configure, but on locally works everything. On "production" I still getting error:

[image]

It looks like module doesn't see this routing, but I have it in "imports" in momentum.module.ts

It's angular 6, very old app.

Any idea where may I find issue?

Comment: I think you should learn to read the error, it tells you that "one of the following must be provided: `component, redirectTo, loadChildren, children`". Compare to your config, you have `loadChildren()` instead. Reading error message will help you resolve problems easier and also help you research easier. So learn that skill. Happy coding!

Comment: Do you think loadChildren is different then loadChildren() ? And this casuse error ?

Comment: oh yes, indeed, one is a property of an object, the other is invoking a function

Comment: mybad, haha, I was looking at `loadChildren` as a function call and `any` as the value, silly me

Comment: So I tried it again with angular 13, everything is working. Maybe Angular 6 more strict on declaration? Not the same, but it does get some quirky: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54340061/error-invalid-configuration-of-route-one-of-the-following-must-be-provided. If you switch to the normal key:value syntax does it work?

Comment: Actually I don't have access to code. Tommorow in morning I will look at this and will inform you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
export const APP_ROUTES: Routes = [
  {
    path: "",
    redirectTo: "momentum",
    pathMatch: "full"
  },
  {
    path: "momentum",
    loadChildren: () => import('./pages/momentum/momentum.module').then(m => m.MomentumModule)
  }
];
```